# How can I create a PDF manual for my project?

Tags: pdf

I need to create a User Manual / Installation Guide for my project, I need to do that as PDF documents.. how can I do my own PDF manuals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write up the document in Word, or your favorite document editor, then use [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) to convert it to a PDF.

Also, this probably belongs on [Super User](http://superuser.com).